# How can I compare my local folder to the Google Drive Copy?

Tags: google-drive

I'm having weird stuff happen where my local copy of my Google Drive folders seems out of synchronisation (despite G Drive saying it's sync'd). For example, the folder names are different and changing one doesn't affect the other.

This is 2GB worth of files so I don't want to just download them all to do a 'diff'.

Comment: Have you restarted Google Drive?  It keeps a counter of synced files, and sometimes does not upload changes if the counter hasn't changed.  (This does not answer your question, though.)

Answer (score 1):

The following is a recipe for a comparison based on filenames alone, not based on file modification times or even content checksums. But it's a start :) Also, the below is to compare two directories that are both on Google Drive, but you can easily adapt it by generating a list of your local files instead with some call to `ls`. (So obviously, the below is a recipe for Linux.)

### 1. Install and configure `drive`

[`drive`](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive) is a Linux command line client for Google Drive. The easiest is to [install it from a package](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive/blob/master/platform_packages.md).

After that:

1. Change into the directory on your computer that includes your whole files synced from Google Drive:

   ```
   cd /home/user/example-dir/
   ```
2. Initialize `drive` with access to your Google Drive. This will ask you to visit a URL and paste the auth code you get there, and save this in a config file in the current directory.

   ```
   drive init
   ```

### 2. Comparing directories

I found that for large Google Drive folders (36 GiB of small files in my case), starting by comparing directories and fixing cases of missing directories was a good first step. (Also because `drive` has no option to copy directories *without* the files inside between two Google Drive folders. Not a problem if you compare between local and remote files only.)

```
drive list -directories -recursive -no-prompt -sort name "source dir" > DirDiff.1-source.txt
drive list -directories -recursive -no-prompt -
```

sort name "dest dir" > DirDiff.2-dest.txt

```
vim -es +"%s/^\/source dir\///g" +"wq" DirDiff.1-source.txt
vim -es +"%s/^\/dest dir\///g" +"wq" DirDiff.2-dest.txt
```

The `drive` command obtain lists of directories from Google Drive, and the `vim` commands remove the differing base directories from each path so that comparison will work properly.

Now to list the directories that are only in the source tree:

```
comm -23 <(sort < DirDiff.1-source.txt) <(sort < DirDiff.2-dest.txt) > DirDiff.3-missing.txt
```

And to show the directories that are only in the destination tree:

```
comm -13 <(sort < DirDiff.1-source.txt) <(sort < DirDiff.2-dest.txt) > DirDiff.4-added.txt
```

About using `comm` like this, [see here](https://serverfault.com/a/68717).

### 3. Comparing files

This works very similar to comparing directory trees:

```
drive list -recursive -no-prompt -sort name "source dir" > 1-source-files.txt
drive list -recursive -no-prompt -sort name "dest dir" > 2-dest-files.txt

vim -es +"%s/^\/source dir\///g" +"wq" DirDiff.1-source.txt
vim -es +"%s/^\/dest dir\///g" +"wq" DirDiff.2-dest.txt
```

To show the files only in the source tree:

```
comm -23 <(sort < FileDiff.1-source.txt) <(sort < FileDiff.2-dest.txt) > FileDiff.3-missing.txt
```

To show the files only in the destination tree:

```
comm -13 <(sort < FileDiff.1-source.txt) <(sort < FileDiff.2-dest.txt) > FileDiff.4-added.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The following **improves on [my other answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125129)** because it allows to compare directories also by modification time and content instead of just the filename. It is also a recipe for Linux.

### 1. Install and configure `drive`

[`drive`](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125129) is a Linux command line client for Google Drive. The easiest is to [install it from a package](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive#diffing).

After that:

1. Change into the directory on your computer that includes your whole files synced from Google Drive:

   ```
   cd /home/user/example-dir/
   ```
2. Initialize `drive` with access to your Google Drive. This will ask you to visit a URL and paste the auth code you get there, and save this in a config file in the current directory.

   ```
   drive init
   ```

### 2. Compare the directories

According to the [drive documentation for Diffing](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive#diffing), you can do the following to compare local and remote directory trees based on file names, modification times and content checksums:

```
drive diff dir_name
```

And the following to compare only based on file names and modificatio times:

```
drive diff -skip-content-check dir_name
```

Also, an alternative method to *only* compare based on content checksums is shown in section [Retrieving MD5 Checksums](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive#retrieving-md5-checksums):

```
diff <(drive md5sum) <(md5sum *)
```